# Documentation for Liferay Hooks

Tags: liferay, hook

I need to listen for user log in and log out events in Liferay. From what little I've been able to find, it seems that using Liferay hooks would be the way to accomplish this. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any information other that at the following link:

http://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/portal-hook-plugins

Does anyone know where I can find further documentation or how I would implement listening for user log in/log out events?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best place to start is probably:

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins.

If you need to get started, you can use the SDK to create a new hook project, it'll give you a shell and the config XML:

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Plugins+SDK

Answer (score 2):

Im covering Liferay hooks in this [article](http://integratingstuff.com/2011/06/05/adding-a-hook-to-liferay/)
I think it gives a good overview and Im sharing some catches I found out along the way in it as well.